# Euclidean distance of sentences

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, nlp

I have scipy sparse matrix with 1,16,098 sentences and 30,119 features. **I want to calculate euclidean distance of each one of them to other and print 5 most similar sentences.**

I am using the CountVectorizer approach to build the vocabulary and encode the words.

But i am getting below error. Please help. I have just started to implement NLP using python.

````
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
features = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)

features.shape
(116098, 30119)

print(len(vectorizer.vocabulary_))
30119

for i in range(0,116098):  
    for j in features:
        print(euclidean_distances(features[j],i))

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-528966153c16> in <module>
      1 for i in range(0,116098):
      2     for j in features:
----> 3         print(euclidean_distances(features[j],i))```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     33     """
     34     def __getitem__(self, key):
---> 35         row, col = self._validate_indices(key)
     36         # Dispatch to specialized methods.
     37         if isinstance(row, INT_TYPES):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py in _validate_indices(self, key)
    128     def _validate_indices(self, key):
    129         M, N = self.shape
--> 130         row, col = _unpack_index(key)
    131 
    132         if isintlike(row):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py in _unpack_index(index)
    274         # not work because spmatrix.ndim is always 2.
    275         raise IndexError(
--> 276             'Indexing with sparse matrices is not supported '
    277             'except boolean indexing where matrix and index '
    278             'are equal shapes.')

IndexError: Indexing with sparse matrices is not supported except boolean indexing where matrix and index are equal shapes.
````

Answer (score 0):

**CountVectorizer** returns sparse matrix.

[sklearn CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

> This implementation produces a sparse representation of the counts using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.

You can convert it to numpy array to use with **euclidean_distance**.

```
features = features.toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably mean:

```
print(euclidean_distances(features[j],features[i]))
```

wgich should work with no problem.